# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for build-in components) or a class/ function( for composite functions) but got : undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation-v5

I am getting below error when I am using @react-navigation/material-top-tabs.

[image]

I have checked my import they are imported correctly. And when I am using previous version of react-native-tabs it is working fine. I havent found similar issue in @react-navigation/material-top-tabs github issues. Below is my implementation :

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';


    renderHeader = () => {
            const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
        
            let initialRootNameScreen = "ScreenA";
            if (
              this.props.route.params != undefined &&
              this.props.route.params != null
            ) {
              if (
                this.props.route.params.from != undefined &&
                this.props.route.params.from != null
              ) {
                initialRootNameScreen = this.getInitialRouteNameFromProfile(
                  this.props.route.params.from
                );
              } else {
                initialRootNameScreen = this.getInitialRouteName();
              }
            } else {
              initialRootNameScreen = this.getInitialRouteName();
            }
            return (
              <Tab.Navigator
                tabBarPosition= "top"
                backBehavior= "none"
                initialRouteName= {initialRootNameScreen}
                lazy= {false}
                removeClippedSubviews= {false}
                animationEnabled= {false}
                swipeEnabled= {false}
        
                tabBarOptions= {{
                  upperCaseLabel: false,
                  scrollEnabled: true,
                  activeTintColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveTintColor: Colors.white_50,
                  labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: Strings.APP_FONT,
                  },
                  style: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.BACKGROUND_BLUE_COLOR,
                    height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 68 : 75,
                  },
                  indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  },
                  tabStyle: {
                    width: viewportWidth / 3,
                    alignSelf: "center",
                  },
                }}
              >
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="ScreenA"
                  children={() => (
                    <ScreenA />
                  )}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="ScreenB"
                  children={() => (
                    <ScreenB />
                  )}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="ScreenC"
                  children={() => (
                    <ScreenC />
                  )}
                />
              </Tab.Navigator>
            );
          };
```

I dont know what I am missing . Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no children props on Tab.Screen component.

Replace it with:

> <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />